# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while running typescript node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, amazon-ec2

I have launched a t2.micro server on aws and while running our application on server with simply "sudo npm start" i am getting :

"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

tried many solution like upgraded node version and  set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=1024 but it didn't work for me so can anyone please help me out to resove this issue ?

start script: tsc && node dist/index.js

Thanks

Comment: So much missing from this question. What is the `scripts.start` entry in `package.json`?

Comment: i have added please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just running out of memory to build your project on a t2.micro. Typescript builds are memory-heavy.

You could

- set up swap memory on the machine (see e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Manually) (which will not be very performant)
- or better yet, build your project (`tsc`) on a beefier machine and only run the compiled Javascript (`node dist/index.js`) on the micro machine.

Comment: Option 2 would have been my recommendation too. You don't want to be building on the same machine on which you deploy your app. This job is better performed elsewhere.

Comment: I have opted second option, i created build on my local machine and then run dist on server. I is working now thanks.